# Is it possible to turn down the fill opacity of an object to 0 in CSS?

Tags: forms, css, opacity

I have been trying to make **a form** that looks like this:

http://designyoutrust.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Sign-In-Widget.png

I already achieved this with Photoshop but I wanna know how to do this **with just pure CSS.** Thanks! :)

Comment: Where is "opacity to 0" in that?

Comment: I said, **FILL opacity** not just opacity. There's a slight difference.

Comment: So what's the difference between "FILL opacity" and "opacity"? And where is an "opacity of 0"?

Comment: http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/layers/opacity-vs-fill/ there, difference between FILL opacity and opacity..

Comment: in order to achieve the same effect, the fill opacity of that object needs to be turned down to 0.. that's what my question is about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
```

You can adjust the last number to something less than 1 but greater than 0 to get exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Isn't that for the background? I'm having trouble with the form not the background.

Comment: You can change the background of the form inputs with that or if the container they are inside of already has that CSS then you can set the background of the inputs to inherit with background:inherit;

Comment: For sure! Did that answer your question?

Comment: thank you so much! I applied what you said and it works just fine :)

Comment: Absolutely! I'm glad to help:-D